# How to get ID of changed file on Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Im integrating google drive API push notification on my website.
Current work:

1. Register web app on dev console, domain etc...
2. OAuth authorization
3. Create channel if does not exist
4. Setup servlet that waits google drive POST request if change happened
5. Change happens on google drive (upload or delete)
6. Servlet catch POST request from google drive when change happens
7. Cached message: `{ "kind": "drive#change", "id": "8664", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/8664"}`

Google drive API representation of a change to a file:

```
{
"kind": "drive#change",
  "id": long,
  "fileId": string,
  "selfLink": string,
  "deleted": boolean,
  "modificationDate": datetime,
  "file": files Resource
}
```

How to get fileId? Why Google Drive does not send me missing fields?? What am I doing wrong?

Watch change code:

```
service -> created ok
channelId -> UUID
channelType -> web_hook
channelAddress -> https://example.com/GoogleDriveWebhook (GoogleDriveWebhook is servlet)
public static Channel watchChange(Drive service, String channelId, String channelType, String channelAddress) {
        Channel channel = new Channel();
        channel.setId(channelId);
        channel.setType(channelType);
        channel.setAddress(channelAddress);
        channel.setExpiration(new Date().getTime() + (600000 * 2));//20 min session for channel (test environment)
        try {
            return service.changes().watch(channel).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Something is wrong with instancing new channel");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

...so obviously app catch change that google drive sends, I am stuck plz help!

Comment: What kind of missing parameters are you looking for? Please check this page for the response resource: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push

Comment: Thx i read it, so this push notifications doesn't really tell me what file is changed, only notifies me that something has changed on google drive or??
Then i tried with "Changes: get" API,  with params: (Drive service, String changeId) where I pass { "kind": "drive#change", **"id": "8664"**, "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/8664"} id like String changedId but I always get "Change not found: 8754" for upload or delete

Answer (score 1):

The POST message sent when a notifications occurs will have the File ID in the headers (see "X-Goog-Resource-ID" below). If you're watching a File or Folder you won't even have a body to parse.

Change notification message for Files resources, which does not include a request body:

```
POST https://example.com/notifications // Your receiving URL.
Content-Type: application/json; utf-8
Content-Length: 0
X-Goog-Channel-ID: 4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66
X-Goog-Channel-Token: 398348u3tu83ut8uu38
X-Goog-Channel-Expiration: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 01:13:52 GMT
X-Goog-Resource-ID:  ret08u3rv24htgh289g
X-Goog-Resource-URI: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/ret08u3rv24htgh289g
X-Goog-Resource-State:  update
X-Goog-Changed: content,properties
X-Goog-Message-Number: 10
```

Change notification message for Changes resources, which includes a request body:

```
POST https://example.com/notifications // Your receiving URL.
Content-Type: application/json; utf-8
Content-Length: 118
X-Goog-Channel-ID: 8bd90be9-3a58-3122-ab43-9823188a5b43
X-Goog-Channel-Token: 245t1234tt83trrt333
X-Goog-Channel-Expiration: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 01:13:52 GMT
X-Goog-Resource-ID:  ret987df98743md8g
X-Goog-Resource-URI: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes
X-Goog-Resource-State:  changed
X-Goog-Message-Number: 23

{
  "kind": "drive#changes",
  "id": "12345",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/12345"
}
```

For more details see https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push#msg-format

Comment: I am doing that @Marco, i get request body as u can see, but problem is: i got body i.e. `{ "kind": "drive#change", "id": "8664", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/8664"}` with id:8864, when i try to call that change it says "404: change not found" so i decreased that number by 1 so it is 8863 then method printChange can find that file, if file was deleted i need to decrees by 2 of biggest changeId to catch what file is deleted. I don't know if this is right approach but it works :S

Comment: Keep in mind that Stack Overflow asks people to ask a single question. If the question evolves, then please open a new question and feel free to link back to this one for context. Your initial question "How do I get the File ID" was what drove my current answer. Hope that helps.