# Google Drive Changes API - change id and file id are invalid

Tags: google-drive-api

I've set up a channel to detect changes on a user's Google Drive. This part works fine and I get a POST to my server each time a change occurs. Example:

```
{ kind: 'drive#change',
  id: '238',
  selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/238' }
```

However, it seems that the data I get in that POST is invalid. The change ID in the POST always seems to be different than the actual ID. For the example above if I try to GET id 238, the response is 'not found'. However, it works if I use 237.

The other confusing thing is the file ID.

[How to get ID of changed file on Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697380/how-to-get-id-of-changed-file-on-google-drive) - this answer states that the file ID is in the header `X-Goog-Resource-ID`. However, same as above, this ID never matches the actual file ID.

Can someone clarify what's going on here? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [`Changes: watch`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/watch) in watching for all the changes to a user's Drive, note that `id` returned in the request body is a UUID or similar unique string that identifies this channel.

You can retrieve the ID of the change and ID of the file associated with the change by using [`Changes: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list). Send HTTP request with this format:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes
```

Optional ID parameters than can be supplied are the following (`changeId` and `fileId` are not included):

- `startChangeId` change ID to start listing changes from.
- `teamDriveId` the Team Drive from which changes will be returned.

If successful, this method returns a response body which includes `id` of the change and `fileId` of file associated to change. Here's the sample structure:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#changeList",
  "etag": etag,
  "selfLink": string,
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "drive#change",
      "id": long,
      "type": string,
      "fileId": string,
      "file": files Resource
    }
  ]
}
```

See [Detect Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) for more information.